# Loading Azure certificate when NOT using custom domain names

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

As I understand if someone doesn't want to use a custom domain name and instead plans on using *.azurewebsite.net domain assigned to the website by Azure, then HTTPS is already enabled with a certificate from Microsoft(I know this is not as secure as using a custom domain name). How would be I able to load this certificate programmatically. Currently I use the following method to load a certificate from local machine or Azure :

```
public static X509Certificate2 LoadFromStore(string certificateThumbprint,bool hostedOnAzure)
{
    var s = certificateThumbprint;

    var thumbprint = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\da-zA-z]", string.Empty).ToUpper();

    var store = hostedOnAzure ? new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser) : new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine); 

    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var certCollection = store.Certificates;

        var signingCert = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

        if (signingCert.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("Cert with thumbprint: '{0}' not found in certificate store. Also number of certificates in the sotre was {1}", thumbprint, store.Certificates.Count));
        }

        return signingCert[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

I assume the culprit is the following line of code :

```
new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
```

because when I get an exception it tells me there is no certificate in the store although I pass the correct certificate Thumbprint(I grab the thumbprint from Chrome manually).

Comment: You may have to ask Azure support to confirm this, but I suspect the SSL certificate isn't actually on the server your code is running on. It's probably on some gateway machine that then forwards the request on to the server your app is actually running on. That's probably why you can't see it in the server's cert store.

Comment: Can you try setting the env variable `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` to `*` in the Azure AppSettings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to access this certificate programmatically in your WebApp as this certificate is not really installed on the Azure WebApp. Azure WebApps have a front-end server which does a "kind of" SSL Offloading so the WebApp actually never has access to this particular certificate. Why exactly you want to read this certificate though ?

Typically if there is a need for certificates in WebApps, you would install **client certificates** and pass them to services for Authentication as mentioned in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/ and those certificates you can access programmatically (code snippet mentioned in the same article)

But I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve by reading the **server certificate**