# Azure web app can't load signing cert from certificate store

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates

I am trying to load a cert follwing [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code), from my windows app server (S1 plan).

I have uploade a known cert to my app service certificate store using the "Bring you own certification (.pfx)" option.

I've added the appsetting WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATE, with a value of *. This should allow all cert to be accessible.

I use the code in the article, which includes this line:

```
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
certThumbprint,
validOnly);
```

It cannot find the cert.

I am sure the thumbprint is correct. However, as a test I checked how many certificates are in the store and it's zero. To do this, I used:

```
certStore.Certificates.Count()
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121151/read-azure-default-wildcard-certificate-from-asp-net-core) says the certificate will never be available, because they are not on the same server. It references another post, which suggest using the approach in this older [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/), but it's the same approach as above..

**Update:**

I see the cert in the portal UI.

No certs are found when I use the kudu console to run:

```
get-childitem -path cert:\CurrentUser\My -Recurse
```

From my box, I run the PowerShell command Get-AzWebAppCertificate, and it finds the cert.

Also, under configuration "Client certificate mode" was set to ignore by default. I changed it to Require, but that didn't help.

Comment: Is this a Windows web app or a Linux web app?

Comment: A windows app service.

Comment: Have you set `Client certificate mode` to `require` in `Configuration`  in Azure web app

Comment: I had not done that.  I just did it, but it didn't help.  I'll updated the post.